# toString methode for class inherrited from arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nlp, tostring

I am doing some Natural Language Processing and therefore implemented a Sentence class is basically an ArrayList with some meta-information. I would like to write overwrite its toString() method, which simply pastes the Strings separated by spaces. I got it working by using the inherited get method, but I was wondering if it would be possible and better (in terms of efficiency and coding praxis) to access the fields directly.

Here is a simplified version of my class:

```
public class Sentence extends ArrayList<String> {
    int sentimentScore;
    String Speaker;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i =0; i < super.size(); i++){
            sb.append(super.get(i));
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use the `get()` method.  Speed-wise, it shouldn't slow your code much (if you believe otherwise, you should write a small program to demonstrate the effect of speed degradation before you hold that belief).  More importantly, `ArrayList` does not expose its internal fields, and that is a good design.  This design shields any future side-effect to others (sub-classes that extends it) should the maintainer decides to change the internal implementation of `ArrayList`.

By the way, you may also want to consider an alternative design -- instead of letting `Sentence` *extend* `ArrayList`, let `Sentence` *contain* `ArrayList`.  This is called the principle of **Composition over inheritance**.

From Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

> **Composition over inheritance** (or **composite reuse principle**) in
>   object-oriented programming is the principle that classes should
>   achieve polymorphic behavior and code reuse by their composition (by
>   containing instances of other classes that implement the desired
>   functionality) rather than inheritance from a base or parent class.
>   This is an often-stated principle of OOP, such as in the influential
>   Design Patterns: "Favor 'object composition' over 'class
>   inheritance'."

Comment: Thank you for the explaination and suggestion for further readings.